# c# properties with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Please point me in the right direction if there is an answer to my question already.

I am new to c# and asp.net mvc. I am working on a project and in this particular project I have a model that reflects how the customer table will be structured when I run a migration. have a look at my Customer model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }

        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Membership Type")]
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        [Min18YearsIfAMember]
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My question, I understand what it means to set string to the name property
ex:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

but what does it mean when some properties are set to their own name and why do we do it?
ex:

```
public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
```

Please give a detailed response. 
Thanks.

Comment: The first `MembershipType` is the data type (could also have been int, string, List, etc).  The second is the property name (could also have been MyMembershipType, MType, TypeOfMember, etc)

Comment: You can give it whatever valid name you want (it has no special meaning)

Comment: `MembershipType` is a navigation property, it just providing navigation to `MembershipType` entity. Of course you can rename given property name to any other valid identifier name (e.g. `public MembershipType MemberType`).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks, this answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I name my classes, properties, methods, fields, etc. I try to follow two guidelines:

1. General naming conventions, e.g. lower case for fields, upper case for properties, etc. More on this [here](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)
2. Common sense - a name explains role of a method, property, etc.

Your code has to be written the way other developers (you in six months in particular) can understand it. And reasonable naming is one of the methods to achieve it.

So for instance, if your property contains customer's address it's reasonable to call it `Address`.

Of course address can be complex - street, city, zip code. Worth having that encapsulated in a separate class. And what would be the best name for the class that keeps all the address details. You guessed it: `Address`.

And so you easily end up with property of type `Address` and with name `Address`. But in both cases it's logical, it's self explanatory to what property holds and what the class holds.

Your example is the same case. Only I suppose the `MembershipType` is an enum rather than a class. But again it makes perfect sense to call the membership type enum `MembershipType` and to call the property that holds the membership type for a customer: `MembershipType`.

Answer (score 0):

In C# Types and Values have distinct namespaces, hence you can unambiguously have a *type* called **MembershipType** and have a *variable* (property, etc.) called **MembershipType**.

Consider the slightly easier to parse variable declaration:

```
MembershipType membershipType = new MembershipType();
membershipType.DoStuff();
... etc.
```

Here the variable name starts with a lower-case by convention - but I **could** write:

```
MembershipType MembershipType = new MembershipType();
MembershipType.DoStuff();
... etc.
```

And the syntax of the language means that it's unambiguous when I mean the **type** and when I mean the **variable**.

Whether it's confusing to the *human reader* is more open to debate however.

For example, note that it's not obvious from what I've written, what the call:

```
MembershipType.DoStuff();
```

resolves to. DoStuff could be a static function on the **type** MemebrshipType, or it could be a function on the **instance** MembershipType.
C# gets around this by enforcing that you can't declare an instance function and a static function with the same name, so it's unambiguous to the compiler. However, unless you know the class MemebrshipType you can't tell which it is from this snippet alone.

Comment: There's one case where type and field/property/method names may collide: Member types. `class C { public enum X {} public X X; }`

Comment: @EdPlunkett *That's* sneaky. I sympathize with the language designers, trying to extend the language while keeping the syntax unambiguous and expressive.

Comment: Language design is tough, especially when you get into six or more versions of a language, with layers of history. They have to think of everything, and work around old decisions.